# Column not being encoded

Tags: python, encoder

I have a column named "education". I'm trying to encode it using Label Encoder but the following error pops up

[I cant post an image so a link to the data is attached below][1]

````
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py in _encode(values, uniques, encode, check_unknown)
    112         try:
--> 113             res = _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)
    114         except TypeError:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py in _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)
     60     if uniques is None:
---> 61         uniques = sorted(set(values))
     62         uniques = np.array(uniques, dtype=values.dtype)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-64573b8efccb> in <module>
----> 1 df_temp['education']=encoder1.fit_transform(df_temp['education'])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py in fit_transform(self, y)
    254         """
    255         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
--> 256         self.classes_, y = _encode(y, encode=True)
    257         return y
    258 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py in _encode(values, uniques, encode, check_unknown)
    115             types = sorted(t.__qualname__
    116                            for t in set(type(v) for v in values))
--> 117             raise TypeError("Encoders require their input to be uniformly "
    118                             f"strings or numbers. Got {types}")
    119         return res

TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['float', 'str']  ```


  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F2uC.png
````

Comment: What is not clear in the error message? You seem to have mixed types in your inputs, but need to have one of the other.

Comment: @pavel im new to this and cant seem to figure it out. The column had some nan values and i replaced them with some random numbers. How to I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
df_temp['education']=encoder1.fit_transform(df_temp['education'].astype(str))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. If you dont mind could you explain why adding '.astype(str)' works?

Comment: This could be due to the way the data is read, i.e. numbers are read as float and text as strings or the datatype was float and changed after the `fillna` operation.

Comment: What i think happened was, u had a column education with string values, u filled an with integers.. that made the column have both string and integers. in the answer above, irrespective of existing types, all everything is converted to string and encoding is done. if what I have said is right, then u cannot fill na of string column with integers